# Why startAnimation method doesn't work inside onTouchEvent method?

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to start the animation when I touch the screen but doesn't work.

**Code**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imgCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_circle);

    up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.up);

    up.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            imgCircle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        imgCircle.startAnimation(up);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

But if I removed `imgCircle.startAnimation(up);` from onTouchEvent and put it in onCreate then will work well.

Can someone tells me why doesn't work inside onTouchEvent?

Comment: to get a callback `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` you must set `imgCircle.setOnTouchListener(this)`

Comment: @rahat `onTouchEvent` Already working when I touch the screen but it ignores this line `imgCircle.startAnimation(up);`

Comment: try with  `imgCircle.post(()->imgCircle.startAnimation(up));`, also put a `Log.d` inside if body to know if it goes there or not,